# Resizing and image processing on many images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api, pixastic

I have several 1000s of images on disk that I need to display a subset of, given user search criteria.  What this means is I could be showing 100s at one time.  Each image is large- 3510x1131 to be exact.  And I need to do some light image processing before they are displayed (adjusting brightness and contrast).

My application to do this is a Web.API app using jQuery.

My first pass was to just pass the URLs to the browser and then size the images and make those adjustments using pixastic.  Works, but it's pretty slow.

I was thinking it would be much faster if I could resize the image before doing the adjustments, but I dont want to create copies and then link to those.  Maybe there is a way to generate the images on the fly and serve them up?  Via REST perhaps?  Bottom line is I need a LOSSY image resize, not just setting width and height using css.

Are there tools out there that I am missing or has anyone done something similar?  I think what Im looking for is exactly like google image search results- but I don't know how they generate those thumbnails- and if I were to adjust brightness/contrast am I doing it on the thumbail (saving time) or the full size image?

Comment: Do you need those adjustments to be applied permanently to your images or only for the purpose of use within your web app?
I don't know either how Google creates the image thumbnails, however, the way I'd do it is, when the images are scanned and saved in the database, make the server generate a down-scaled copy of it.
Regarding your question, I'd first adjust those thumbnails and have them linked to their original counterparts. Then, when (pre?)loaded, apply adjustments to the originals before displaying them.
I've made this a comment because I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for...

Comment: Thanks- this is pretty close.  The adjustments are temporary- no need to persist them.  And the real problem (and hence the question) is that I dont control how the images are stored.  Plus there are many 1000s already- I was looking for an in memory dynamic solution.

Comment: Well that's a little bit more difficult. JavaScript initially wasn't intended to work with images a lot. However, nowadays there are possibilities to manipulate images. I know of methods making use of the [data:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) URI scheme. There's probably an API floating somewhere around the Internet... I don't know much about asp.net though. All I think I know is that it is a serverside language. Can you cache created thumbnails of images you have loaded? And can you use a serverside API to disburden the clients? Does your app even support this?

Comment: Ill look into the data uri scheme stuff... but Im working right now to do the heavy lifting on the serverside- the pixastic stuff works great, I think if I can just serve up scaled down images via web.api (rest) this might help out...

Comment: I wouldn't recommend working directly with the data URI scheme. You'll be using raw hexadecimal bits and bytes of the actual files. Can be tedious work with... ;) Like I said previously, it may be a good idea to cache those thumbnails to save your server from double work. Depending on how big the project is, there are lots of optimizations one could use. The cache obviously is good if many users will access the app.